# Is it possible to implement ANOVA analysis with categorical dependant variable?

Tags: anova, multilevel-analysis, survey, multinomial-logit

I have some survey data which tracks the employment status of individuals over time. I am doing an analysis on the effects of different independant variables on occupation, and one thing I wish to capture is how important factors operating at different scales are (see below for description of data). I originally tried to capture this by implementing a multi-level, multinomial regression model. However, the only R package I could find which was able implement this kind of model was `brms`, which uses Bayesian linear regression. However, the models consistently failed to converge.

I am therefore now trying to capture the effect of factors occuring at 4 different levels using a multivariate ANOVA analysis. This analysis would involve a categoric dependant variable (occupation) and a series of nested independant variables (year, person ID, household ID, UK region). However, from what I have seen from online forums, performing a traditional ANOVA analysis with a categoric dependant variable violates several important model assumptions, rendering the results useless.

**I therefore have several questions:**

**1) Is there a way to implement implement an ANOVA analysis with a categoric dependant variable?**

**2) If so, are there any R or Python packages capable of implementing this kind of analysis?**

**3) If not, does anyone have any alternative suggestions for how I could capture the importance of different scales of effects (e.g. individual, household, regional/national) to employment status?**

*Description of data:* I have a sample of 26,500 individuals that provided yearly responses over a 10-year period. My dependant variable is a nominal categoric variable I call ‘occupation trajectory’ which captures changes in individual’s occupational status over this 10-year period (e.g. 'stable full-time employment', 'education to full-time employment'). It has 8 categories that were calculated using a clustering method called sequence analysis (for an example, see page 978 here: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s11187-019-00312-z.pdf; or page 833 here: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00168-016-0771-8.pdf). The variable is time-invariant, as it represents a 10-year trajectory, rather than yearly responses.

I also have a group of independent variables linked to different scales of effects. Individual factors include age, income, gender, marital status, country of origin and level of education. Household factors include household size, number of children and housing tenure (whether the home is owned, mortgaged or rented). Contextual factors include national employment rate and national median income. These independent variables are currently being used in a regular multinomial regression model.

In addition, I also have some nested variables that are directly linked to the scales I am trying the capture. These are year, person ID, household ID, 'UK region where the individual lives'.

Comment: Yes, you could use some glm (generalized linear model), which makes for analogies of anova analysis.  For a detailed answer, you need to give more details of your problem, specifically, the nature of your response variable. Ordinal? Nominal? How many levels? sample size? ...

Comment: Your statement "my machine was unable to cope with the computational requirements" might represent a problem with model formulation rather than an inherent limitation of your computer. Unless your data set is enormous, modern computers should be able to handle the type of multinomial regression you seem to have tried. When you add the details that @kjetilbhalvorsen requests to your question, please also specify the problem or warning that was reported when you tried to run your model. Please edit the question rather than adding a comment; comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thanks so much for responding! I have tried to add the additional detail above.

Comment: @EdM Thanks so much as well! I have added more detail about package and the nature of the errors I encountered in the question. However, I would have to pull an old version of my GitHub repository to retrieve and run the actual code and replicate the error, which I am reluctant to do unless absolutely necessary. Please let me know if the above information is sufficient.

Comment: The simple strict answer to the question in your title is "No"; ANOVA is for continuous outcomes. Multi-category outcomes that aren't ordered can be modeled with multinomial regression, a type of generalized linear model. That's analogous in some ways to ANOVA or ANCOVA, but it's best to be precise in terminology. The intricacies of multi-level survey analysis are beyond my expertise. I've added the `survey` tag to the question to try to get attention from those having such expertise.